# How do I turn a string into JSON and then send it to the Parse API using jQuery?

Tags: json, api, jquery

I am building a simple chat app.  I am trying to create a function that will take a string as input, then send the input to the Parse server using JSON, ajax, and jQuery.

My non-working code:

```
Chat.send = function(str){
    var mssg = {"text": str};
    mssg1 = JSON.stringify(mssg);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/____",
      data: mssg1,
      success: success,
      dataType: "json",
    });
};
```

When I try to use this, the console does not show the object as being posted, nor does it log any errors.

Comment: what is it, that is not working? errors?

Comment: the last `,` is not necessary

Comment: It depends on how the server is accessing the data. You might have to provide a key for it, i.e. `data: {data: mssg1}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a JSON string using this method. Just pass the JSON object itself without stringifying it.

```
Chat.send = function(str){
    var mssg = {"text": str};
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/____",
      data: mssg,
      success: success,
      dataType: "json",
    });
};
```

See the "data" section of the jQuery AJAX API docs:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
Chat.send = function(str){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/____",
      data: str,
      success: success,
      dataType: "json",
    });
};
```

You dont have to manually convert the object to JSON, just specify json as datatype.

Comment: While jQuery can handle such input just well, the data won't be sent as JSON. The `dataType` option is to tell jQuery how to handle the **response**, not the request.